# Understanding the subnet mask

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

I've been reading up trying to understand what a subnet and the subnet mask is exactly, but I'm still a bit confused.

When I run ipconfig, the Ethernet adapter LAN Connection might say something like the following:

```
IPv4 Address: 10.69.6.93 
Subnet Mask 255.255.254.0
```

Am I correct to assume the following:

- My network administrator has configured the network to have 32768 subnets
- Each subnet may consist of up to 510 hosts
- The network streches from 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.254
- The subnet I happen to be in is from 10.69.6.1 - 10.69.7.254
- I cannot ping anyone outside my subnet
- Hosts on other subnets have the same subnet mask as I have

Comment: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers u can refer here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My network administrator has configured the network to have 32768 subnets

Your calculations would be correct given two assumptions:

1. that the whole network is a /8 (255.0.0.0),
2. and that all subnets are of equal size – that is, all /23's (255.255.254.0).

However, you **cannot** automatically make these assumptions.

1. You cannot determine the whole network's size purely from its address. Only the private-use reservation is a /8, but actual routing has been entirely classless for quite a while now – all unicast networks must have their size (netmask or /prefix) specified explicitly.

   It is true that **in earlier days** (the classful+subnetting era) the whole 10.x network would have been a "class A" and therefore strictly a /8, but that is not necessarily the case anymore.

   It is of course very common to just use the entire 10.0.0.0/8 reservation as a single network. But it's also possible that your network administrator might have decided on using 10.64.0.0/12 or 10.69.0.0/16 as the main network.
2. You also cannot assume that all subnets are of equal size. The subnet mask only defines *this* subnet's size – your host does not need to know anything about distant subnets (only the router knows that). It is very common for an IPv4 network to be a mix of /24's, /16's, /20's, /31's, et cetera.

> Each subnet may consist of up to 510 hosts

Possibly yes, but **only** if you assume that all subnets in the network are of the same size. As said earlier, that's not always the case.

> The network streches from 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.254

Possibly yes, but **only** if you assume that the network is a /8 (255.0.0.0). As stated earlier, you cannot make that assumption based on just the network's address.

> The subnet I happen to be in is from 10.68.6.1 - 10.68.7.254

Yes, if you're describing the addresses available to hosts. But for routing purposes, it would be more correct to include 10.69.6.0 – 10.69.7.255 as well. *(I assume the '68' is a typo.)*

The reason is that intermediate routers don't know if a given address is a host or not, because they don't know how large a distant subnet is. Therefore they'll forward packets for 10.69.6.0 the same way as 10.69.6.1. (Only when the packet reaches the final router, directly attached to the network, is when the 'network' and 'broadcast' addresses actually get special treatment.)

> I cannot ping anyone outside my subnet

Likely correct, if you have no gateway configured whatsoever.

But just because the "IP configuration" panel doesn't show a *default* gateway, does not automatically mean you don't have any *specific* gateways (that is, static routes configured in the 'Advanced' subpanel). Admittedly, this is fairly rare on normal hosts, but shouldn't be overlooked.

You can see all routes of all types via `netstat -r -n` or `route -4 print`.

> Hosts on other subnets have the same subnet mask as I have

No. Each subnet can be of different size.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It cleared up a lot for me, although I think I have to read more for it to be intuitive and make sense.

Comment: The 68 was indeed a typo.

Comment: Read articles which talk about how a routing table works, preferably those which discuss CIDR prefix-lengths instead of netmasks. (Priority rules are more intuitive with those.) Once you know how routes work, the purpose of a "subnet mask" and e.g. the reason why subnets can be of different sizes should become clear.